# Caching in FF and Safari vs. IE9 and Chrome

Tags: caching, browser, actionscript

I just began to explore browsers other than IE and I came across the following behaviour:

In IE9, Flash movies (loading external mp4s) are cached so when you go back to the page it loads from the local copy, whereas in other browsers they seem to start downloading the movie again instead of using a cached copy.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I think Chrome also uses caching like IE9. so the question refers to Firefox and Safari only.

**LATEST:** Ok I have played around with Safari and Chrome and the issue is not to do with the caching. The issue is in flash swf, when I am loading external movies into the same player because I am using `LOAD` in actionscript it loads from the beginning because of the difference of the MP4 file. whereas using the same clip it uses the cached movie.

Is there a way caching the played movies from actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the horrors of Flash caching files as well, however it was FF and Chrome that gave me the most trouble. Unfortunately, there is no way to control how the browsers cache. That is up to the user of the browser. Through an SWF you can not tell the browser NOT to cache and you can not tell the browser TO cache.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: yeah you are right. i found that after experimenting with browsers. for a change in IE9 this issue does not happen only in FF, chrome and safari. im just going to load separate players for each movie because the swf is not large. and this works in all browsers, i think. thanks for you input.

Comment: be nice to him and give him the reputation ;)

Comment: sorry my first comment was foolish. i have realised that there was no caching only the sample movie was small enough to appear it was being cached.